# How to differentiate between empty collection & collection with no data after executing a query

Tags: laravel

I have two query from which one is executed on some particular event.
Now, I have to differentiate between collection which is empty(query when not executed) & collection that fetch no data from database.

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $owned = DB::table('eusers')
                ->join('tasks', 'eusers.id', '=', 'tasks.task_assign_to')
                ->where('tasks.task_assign_to', '=',$id)
                ->get();
    $filteredData = DB::table('tasks')
                ->join('eusers', 'eusers.id', '=', 'tasks.task_assign_to')
                ->where('tasks.task_status', '=', $filterKey)
                ->where('tasks.task_assign_to', '=', $id)
                ->get();
    return view('euser.dashboard', compact('owned', 'filteredData'));
}
```

Now what I want is something like this :

```
<div class="row">
    @if(isset($filteredData))
      @foreach($filteredData as $data)
         //Some code here...
      @endforeach
    @else
      @foreach($owned as $data)
         //Some code here...
      @endforeach
    @endif
  </div>
```

**Note : I got results only when $filteredData have some data in it.**

Answer (score 0):

Add condition of not empty as below:

```
<div class="row">
@if(isset($filteredData) && !empty($filteredData->toArray()))
  @foreach($filteredData as $data)
     //Some code here...
  @endforeach
@else
  @foreach($owned as $data)
     //Some code here...
  @endforeach
@endif
```